# How to link two ViewModels together via @Published variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Say I have

```
class ViewModelA:ObservableObject {
  @Published var test = true
}

class ViewModelB:ObservableObject {
    @Published var model:Model
    init() {
       model = load() //load some data
    }
    func reload() {
       //how to make this func called when test is set to true?
    }
}
```

Comment: View models shouldn’t know about each other. Move any shared info down to a manager.

Comment: @loremipsum I dont know the manager pattern, can you provide an example

Comment: It isn’t a “manager pattern” it is MVVM, a manager is just where the business logic for the model located. I don’t have my Mac now but there are plenty of tutorials on the subject, this question gets asked all the time on SO and there are several different approaches you should be able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for the ViewModelB to subscribe a sink to the publisher notification of changes of test from ViewModelA and then you can detect and get new values sent. You need to import Combine, See code below. This can get quite messy quite quickly, but there are circumstances where I have needed to use this and it works reliably. You also need a context where modelB can see modelA or can be passed it.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModelA:ObservableObject {
@Published var test = true
 }

class ViewModelB:ObservableObject {
@Published var model :Model

var modelA = ViewModelA()   // Need access to modelA somewhere.
var allCancel: [any Cancellable] = []

init() {
  //  model = load() //load some data
    let testSink = modelA.$test.sink { newValue in // Subscribes to the publisher
        // Run your code.....
        self.reload(newValue)       // code to run and evaluate new value
    }
    
    self.allCancel.append(testSink) // Variable must be saved to keep subscription
}                                   // Can be removed from array to stop

func reload(_ newValue: Bool) {
   //how to make this func called when test is set to true?
}
```

}

Comment: Accepted. Can you also provide a good design where modals can reference each other?

Comment: Do you mean modal such as Sheet Views etc. One way is to pass the same ViewModel Observable Object in to both as dependency or in the Environment. As they both have the same ViewModel object behind them the data is effectively shared. Both can then respond. Sharing ViewModels behind many views is a great way to sync data around the app. You just need to be careful it does not become hugely swollen with logic from every view. I try to separate central global app state in a shared view model and view driving logic in to sections of the app or simple @States on the views themselves.

Comment: just because it's possible doesn't mean you should do it, it's better to learn the View struct